# Symfony - how to add field type year in entity

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, entity, symfony5, php-7.4

I'm trying to add field in entity of type year.
Like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="year")
 */
private $release;
```

Symfony docs says there is no such option for Date/Time Type for entity fields, only
following Date/Time Types:

- **datetime (or datetime_immutable)**
- **datetimetz (or datetimetz_immutable)**
- **date (or date_immutable)**
- **time (or time_immutable)**

Is it possible to declare field type as **year**?

Comment: You can create [custom types](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/cookbook/custom-mapping-types.html), but I don't quite see the benefit of one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no Year Type in doctrine. but you can still use a string to save it, and convert it to datetime object in getters/setters.